# How to get my expected search result using grep on Linux

Tags: linux, sh

I am trying to find out which files contains this text '`roads`' on the server, so I use this command: `grep -rl 'roads'`. But it shows lots of such files:

```
./res/js/.svn/entries
./res/js/.svn/all-wcprops
./res/styles/.svn/entries
./res/styles/.svn/all-wcprops
./res/images/.svn/entries
```

I do not want this folder `.svn` show in the search result because this is just for version control, it means nothing for me, so is there a way that I can do this: if the result contains `.svn`, then it does not show up in the final result. e.g. below three files contain the text '`roads`':

```
 check.php 
./res/js/.svn/entries
./res/js/.svn/all-wcprops
```

Then the result only shows:

```
check.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to simply grep away your false positives:

```
grep -rl roads . | grep -v '/\.svn/'
```

If you want to be more efficient and not spend time searching through the SVN files, you can filter them away before grepping through them:

```
find -type f | grep -v '/\.svn/' | xargs grep -l roads
```

Answer (score 1):

grep has a feature to exclude a particular directory, called "--exclude-dir", so simply you can pass .svn as "--exclude-dir" param, like below:

```
        "grep -rl --exclude-dir=.svn ./ -e roads"
```